# How is path look like for password.key in Android 10?

Tags: android-10

I have my own Android 10 locked up with a PIN (encrypted Android 10) - and then later I have forgotten the correct PIN how it looks (has only numbers).

Now I found a solution for Android < 6.0 or Android < 7.0 where it is easy
simply to delete the password.key file with adb like :

> adb shell rm /data/system/password.key

How would this look for Android 10.0 resp. Android 10.1 ?!
I do not want to make a factory reset, because I have no backup of this encrypted device.

Thank you for answering this !

Comment: As you write the device is encrypted and the used encryption key can only be accessed if you enter the correct PIN after a reboot. So no matter what you delete you won't be able to access the data without the correct PIN unless you have never shut down or rebooted device since the PIN was entered correctly the last time.

Comment: you probably asking for *locksettings.db* but even if device is unencrypted and adb is authorized */data* cannot accessed anyway (except you have root access)